# App.config Transformation is not working with Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, config-transformation

in Visual Studio 2015 I created a new solution and developed a windows service. I have an app.config file and created app.realease.config file with a small transformation rule. I also configured the project and during my local builds everthing is fine. I've got a transformed config file wile build with the release configuration. To deploy the windows service I added a Visual Studio Installer Setup Project. When I build this project with the realese Configuration I get my setup files. The installation works fine, only the config file is the original one without the transformation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same here today with VS 2013. Using "Configuration Transform" and "Visual Studio Installer Projects" extensions. "bin" folder contains the expected config (transformed) but not the "msi"...